# Trying to implement imfilter, but the image turns red

Tags: matlab, image-processing, smoothing

So I want to implements imfilter in matlab, without using the function itself. Here's what I came up through until now:

```
   % Menampilkan gambar sebelum di smoothing
    gambar = imread('bird.jpg');
    ukuran = size(gambar);
    figure
    imshow(gambar)

    % Menampilkan gambar setelah di smoothing
    gambardouble = im2double(gambar);
    filter = ones(3) * 1/9;
    gambarfinal = zeros(ukuran);

for i = 2:ukuran(1)-1
    for j = 2:ukuran(2)-1
        temp= gambardouble(i-1:i+1,j-1:j+1) .* filter;
        gambarfinal(i,j) = sum(temp(:));
    end
end

disp(gambarfinal);
figure
imshow(gambarfinal);
```

Now, the normal image is fine. But the output is become red like this:
[image]

Any ideas what went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gambar` seems to be a RGB image, size NxMx3. In `gambarfinal = zeros(ukuran);` you generate a zero matrix of size NxMx3.  But then you apply the filter only to the red band, leaving the other two bands zero = black, which yields a red image.

To also apply the filter to the other bands, you could e.g. apply the filter on all 3 bands at once:

```
...

% generate 3-d filter
filter = ones(3,3,3) * 1/9;

...

% extract a 3x3x3 cube instad of a 3x3 patch
temp= gambardouble(i-1:i+1,j-1:j+1,:) .* filter;

% sum first along 1. dimension, then along the 2.dimension. This gives a 1x1x3 column.
gambarfinal(i,j,:) = sum(sum(temp,1),2);
```

If you feel more comfortable with it, you could instead generate a loop over the other two bands - but that would be much slower.

#### Edit

The colon operator `:` returns all elements of a matrix in that dimension. E.g. for a 2 dimensional matrix `A`, `A(:,2)` will return the second column of `A`. Likewise, for a 3 dimensional matrix `A(2,5,:)` will return all elements along the 3. Dimension (a vector). Also note that `A(2,5)` is implicit the same as `A(2,5,1)`.

In your case `gambardouble(i-1:i+1,j-1:j+1)` will returns a 3x3 window of the 1. layer (red) of the 3-dimensional matrix. By changing it to `gambardouble(i-1:i+1,j-1:j+1,:)` you will like the examples above also get the same pixels in the other layers. Therefore in your case, `temp` will be a 3x3x3 cube.

`sum(temp,1)` sums the cube along the 1. dimension, returning a 1x3x3 matrix. Then by also taking the sum along the 2. dimension with `sum(... , 2)` you turn it into a 1x1x3 vector, where each element belongs to one band.

`gambarfinal(i,j,:)` is the RGB values at position `(i,j)` which we replace with the new values.

For more information, read the [colon documentation](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html)

Comment: This solution works! I would like to know why should I use temp= gambardouble(i-1:i+1,j-1:j+1,:) .* filter; and gambarfinal(i,j,:) = sum(sum(temp,1),2);. Mind to explain? I'm kind of new to this technology